# Transpiling ES6 to ES5 with module loading and class inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying find the best/working solution for transpiling my ECMA Script 6 code to ES5. I'd like to use a module loader and make use of inheritance. The closest I've got so far is by using Babel 6 with the `es2015` preset, and `transform-es2015-modules-systemjs` plugin. Here is my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-systemjs"]
}
```

And my files are structured like this:

```
- dist
    (transpiled files in the same structure as the src folder)
- src
    - classes
        - Point.js
        - ColorPoint.js
    app.js
index.html
```

The contents of `app.js` looks like this:

```
import ColorPoint from 'classes/ColorPoint.js';

let cp = new ColorPoint(25, 8, 'green');
console.log(cp.toString()); // '(25, 8) in green'
```

The definition of `Point.js` looks like this:

```
export default class Point {
```

And the definition of `ColorPoint.js` looks like this:

```
import Point from 'classes/Point.js';
export default class ColorPoint extends Point {
```

And just for completeness, the important part of `index.html` looks like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        baseURL: 'dist'
    });

    System.import('app.js');
</script>
```

I am transpiling the whole src folder to the dist folder using the command:

```
babel src -d dist
```

The problem is that Babel adds a single line to the top of the transpiled `ColorPoint.js` file which breaks System.js at runtime. The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Module http://localhost/es6-tutorial/dist/classes/ColorPoint.js interpreted as global module format, but called System.register.
```

But when I remove this line at the top of this file it works again:

```
function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && obj.constructor === Symbol ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }
```

I guess this might be a bug in the transpiler. I hoping to get some guidance from someone who's successfully implemented inheritance and module loading before. Or maybe point me to a current working example which I can look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Kendrick Burson who put me on the right track, I was able to solve this. All I needed to do was change the format in the System.js config. So my `index.html` now looks like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        baseURL: 'dist',
        meta: {
            'classes/*': {
                format: 'register'
            }
        }
    });

    System.import('app.js');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow,  I am having the same problem!  I was using traceur to transpile my code just fine and things have been running well for the past year, but traceur is not very active and there are more language features available in babel, so I decided to switch.

The process has been a bit tedious and now I am falling down on this very issue; a class that extends a base class is transpiled with a statement that preceeds the System.register call.

From the SystemJS docs on modules it states the precedence of module format identification:

> ### Module format detection
>
> When the module format is not set, automatic regular-expression-based detection
>      is used. This module format detection is never completely accurate, but caters
>      well for the majority use cases.
>
> The module format detection happens in the following order:
>
> 1. **System.register** / System.registerDynamic If the source code starts with a number
>      of comments, followed by **System.register** or System.registerDynamic **as the first
>      line of code.**
> 2. **ES modules** The source is only detected as an ES module if it contains explicit
>      module syntax - valid import or export statements.
> 3. **AMD** modules The presence of a valid AMD define statement in the code.
> 4. **CommonJS** modules The presence of require(...) or exports / module.exports
>      assignments
> 5. **Global** This is the fallback module format after all the above fail.

So, the auto detection fails with inherited classes as the babel transpiler adds the mentioned line at the head of the file.

What needs to happen is add a config to tell systemjs that those compiled js files are in **register** format.

I have been playing around with *meta* && *packages* in  **system.config.js** trying to find the magic incantation to identify all **'**/*.js'** files in my build folder as 
**{format: 'register'}** but cannot get the glob, or path, or something quite right.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for putting me on the right track! In my case I changed the code in `index.html` to this and it worked!:

`System.config({
            baseURL: 'dist',
            meta: {
                'classes/*': {
                    format: 'register'
                }
            }
        });`